# If both $T_w$ and $\bar T$ are diagonalizable and have no common eigenvalues, then $T$ is diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra

> If both $T_w$ and $\bar T$ are diagonalizable, then so is $T$.
> $T$ is an linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ and $W$ is an nontrivial $T$-invariant subspace of $V$, $\bar{T}:V/W\to V/W$ by $\bar{T}(v+W)=T(v)+W$.

Since $T_w$ and $\bar T$ are diagonalizable, there are  ordered bases $\gamma=\{v_1,\dots,v_k\}$ and $\alpha=\{v_{k+1}+W,\dots,v_n+W\}$ such that $[T_w]_\gamma$ and $[\bar T]_\alpha$ are diagonal matrices.

By some modification, we can assume that $v_{k+j}$ is an eigenvector of $T$ for $1\le j\le n-k$. ( I have already knew how to do it. )

I want tot show that $\beta=\{v_1,\dots, v_n\}$ is a basis for $V$ by proving that $V$ is the direct sum of $W$ and $\text{span(}\delta)$, where $\delta=\{v_{k+1},\dots,v_n\}$.

I have already prove that $W\cap \text{span(}\delta)=\emptyset$ and $\delta$ is linearly independent. But I have no idea how to prove $V=W+\text{span(}\delta)$. Could someone give. me some advice? Thanks a lot.

Comment: We can simply calculate dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to see it. Since $T_W$ and $\bar T$ is diagonalizable, $\operatorname{min. poly }(T_W)$ and $\operatorname{min. poly }(\bar T)$ splits into distinct linear factors. These polynomials have no common root as $T_W$ and $\bar T$ have no common eigen value. Consider $p(x)=\operatorname{min. poly }(T_W)\operatorname{min. poly }(\bar T)$ which also splits splits into distinct linear factors. You can show that $p(T)=0$. So the minimal polynomial of $T$ splits into distinct linear factors and hence $T$ is diagonalizable